# How can i export maya binary (.mb) file into openGL in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es, maya, after-effects

I have .mb(Maya Binary) file that was created by maya with animation. I want to use this file in my OpenGL Project in iOS. I have searched for this and i got a result some  script converts all of the Maya binary (.mb) files in a given directory to OpenGL Performer binary (.pfb) format.

But how to use this .pfb file.
can anyone tell me how can i use .mb or .pfb file in my openGL project in iOS

Answer (score 0):

From my knowledge of maya, you would be better off using the .ma file rather than the .mb because it is written in uncompressed text, so you could better interpret it. An example is that some animators use the ma file format so that they can open it up with a text editor and change values directly if something gets messed up that causes maya to crash (I've had it happen before). But anyway, if you do that then you could probably create something that extracts the info from it.